# How to cause ng-show to activate after a promise resolves

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-show

I have an ng-repeat with an ng-show inside. The variable passed to ng-show is not fully initiated until a promise in my controller resolves.

This is causing the ng-show to always end up reading a "falsey" object because it is reading the value before the promise finishes getting the correct results from the service.

Is there a way to cause the ng-show to wait until my objects are fully initialized?

Comment: Can you post some code with a concrete example?

Comment: numerous ways this can be approached from routing `resolve` to defining variable in controller to using `$q.all()`. Need a lot more context and code shown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a control variable, like `$scope.loaded = false` and make your promise set it to `true`. Then you can use both conditions in your `ng-show`.

Answer (score 1):

On the page load set a flag value.

```
app.controller({.......
$scope.flagPromiseWait = false;
.........
.........
var onSuccess = function (result){
.............
............
$scope.flagPromiseWait = true;
},
var onError = function(err){
............
    }
});
```

and on HTML use

```
<div ng-show="$scope.flagPromiseWait">...........<div>
```

Comment: This should be not `<div ng-show="$scope.flagPromiseWait">` but the same thing without $scope var inside ng-show attribute. Like this: `<div ng-show="flagPromiseWait">`